# How do I rotate this 2-D array using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm working through some practice problems to sharpen up my Ruby skills and I'm working on the problem where I have to rotate a 2-D array by 90 degrees.  This is the input:

```
image = [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,0,1,2],
        [3,4,5,6]
    ]
```

And the expected output is:

```
image = [
        [3,9,5,1],
        [4,0,6,2],
        [5,1,7,3],
        [6,2,8,4]
    ]
```

This is the code I have written which is printing out the incorrect output:

```
def matrix(image)
    y = image.length
    for i in 0..y-1
        for j in 0..y-1
            image[i][j] = image[i][y-j-1]
        end
    end
    image
end
```

This is the output from that code:

```
image = [
    [4, 3, 3, 4], 
    [8, 7, 7, 8], 
    [2, 1, 1, 2], 
    [6, 5, 5, 6]
]
```

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See the answer I posted, similar to your approach.

Comment: @AlokAnand Cool thanks a lot, I really like your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image = [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,0,1,2],
        [3,4,5,6]
    ]

y = image.length
new_arr = []
for i in 0..y-1
  new_arr << image[i].dup
  for j in 0..y-1
    if y-j-1 == i || i > y-j-1
      image[i][j] = new_arr[y-j-1][i]
    else
      image[i][j] = image[y-j-1][i]
    end
  end
end

#=> [[3, 9, 5, 1], [4, 0, 6, 2], [5, 1, 7, 3], [6, 2, 8, 4]]
```

Answer (score 9):

I'd do using [`Array#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
image = [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,0,1,2],
        [3,4,5,6]
    ]

image.transpose.map(&:reverse)
# => [[3, 9, 5, 1], [4, 0, 6, 2], [5, 1, 7, 3], [6, 2, 8, 4]]
```

Comment: OK cool answer, but how do I fix my code that I wrote to output the same result?

Comment: @Jamaal Why do you want to stick with your code when this is a clean, efficient, simple way of achieving your goal?

Comment: @pjs I just want to know why the code I wrote doesn't work, that's all

Comment: @ArupRakshit Ya I know, but I'm not sure how to fix it to get it to work.  What would you suggest I do to fix it?

Comment: @Jamaal If you want to use loop, you need to rewrite code again. Your current approach is wrong totally. If I get some time, I would update with looping, but I can't fix your one, as total logic is wrong. Your looping more than what you actually need. You are swapping data, but only in one cell. That way you are also loosing data too.

Comment: @Jamaal It doesn't work because you're assigning values to `image[i][j]` without preserving the value that was already there so you can move *it* to another location.  Think of swapping in languages that don't have parallel assignment - you can't just say `a = b; b = a`, you have to do something like `tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem in you solution is that you change the array that you iterate over. Think about a `[2x2]` matrix:

```
[
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
]
```

Now, you iterate the first index (0,0), and assign it the location on (1,0) now your matrix is:

```
[
  [3, 2],
  [3, 4]
]
```

Now, no matter the rest of your algorithm - you lost the `1` at location (0,0)!

You might have more bugs in the algorithm - but this is your show-stopper - you should create a new array, and not overwrite the existing one.

Comment: yes..exactly..OP is loosing data, in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea without using `transpose` would be to use `map` to create the new array matrix:

```rb
image = [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,0,1,2],
        [3,4,5,6]
    ]

(0...image.length).map do |i| 
  (0...image.length).map do |j|
    image[j][i]
  end
end.map(&:reverse)
# => [[3, 9, 5, 1], [4, 0, 6, 2], [5, 1, 7, 3], [6, 2, 8, 4]]
```